# yii2 404 page not found when trying remove /web from URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to remove this /web from the URL in Yii2 basic template with .htaccess files. And I found a solution for it already but a problem has occurred!
So the solution I have found earlier is:

1. Put in root/web folder .htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    
    RewriteRule . index.php
```

2. Put in root folder .htaccess:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    IndexIgnore */*
    RewriteEngine on
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
    RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

3. Add in **config/web.php** in **request** part **'baseUrl'=> ''**

The problem occured after steps 2 and 3 are made. Browser tells:

> Not Found
> The requested URL /web/index.php was not found on this server.
> Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at localhost Port 80

All this happens when I'm doing it on my local server which is WAMP. I tried to place this project on free hosting and everything seem to work there. So how can I fix this problem on my local server? Why does it give me the 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

Try in the root .htaccess replace

```
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1
```

on

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [L,PT]
```